# Move ctor is not getting invoked

Tags: c++, oop, move-semantics, move-constructor

Below is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class mystring {
    private:
        char * ptr;
    public:
        mystring() {
            ptr = new char[1];
            ptr[0] = '\0';
        }
        mystring(const char * obj) {
            cout<<"param called "<<endl;
            int len = strlen(obj);
            ptr = new char[len+1];
            strcpy(ptr,obj);
        }
        mystring(mystring& obj) {
            cout<<"copy called "<<endl;
            ptr = new char[strlen(obj.ptr)+1];
            strcpy(ptr, obj.ptr);
        }
        mystring(mystring&& obj) noexcept{
            cout<<"shallow copy created "<<endl;
            ptr = obj.ptr;
            obj.ptr = NULL;
        }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, mystring& obj) {
            out<<obj.ptr<<endl;
            return out;
        }
};

int main() {
    mystring s1 = move("Hello World");
    mystring s2 = s1;
    return 0;
}
```

When I say `mystring s1 = move("Hello World");` My understanding is that move ctor should be invoked but for some reason the output of the above code is `param called copy called`. I am not sure why param ctor is getting invoked for that when I am trying to do a shallow copy. Can somebody help me understanding the output please. Thanks!

Comment: A move is not a shallow copy.

Comment: Consider what`move("Hello World")` is.  It's not a `mystring`.

Comment: "Hello World" is not a string, it is a char[12], `move()`ing it will convert it to `char[8]&&`.

Comment: Your move constructor would do a shallow copy if it didn't do `obj.ptr = NULL;`. It would also be very surprising since that's not what moving is expected to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
mystring s1 = move("Hello World");
```

you are `move`ing the string literal `"Hellow Word"`, not an object of type `mystring`.

```
int main() {
    mystring s1 = move("Hello World"); // moving a c-string, not very useful
    mystring s2 = s1; // calls copy constructor
    mystring s3 = std::move(s1); // new line, calls move constructor
    return 0;
}
```

will print

```sh
param called 
copy called 
shallow copy created
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cxh7qrzcd

Finally, note the the "shallow copy" is not at all a good description of what move doest.